# sql update command with skip primary key duplicates

Tags: sql-update, primary-key

I have two tables T1(col1,col2,col3) and T2(col4,col5,col6)

Only for T1 , col1 is primary key.

I need to update col1=col4, col2 = col5, col3=col6 where col1=col4 or col1=col5

There are chances that primary key is getting duplicated... and update command does not work

basically update primary key with out duplicates in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to update col1 as you are updating the row with same primary key.
col1 is primary key of T1, so it won't be duplicated.

The query should be `UPDATE T1 SET col2=col5, col3=col6 WHERE col1=col4`

in case of col1 != col4 and col1 = col5 please execute the query `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE col1 = col4`

if the number of rows in result array > 0 then skip

Comment: hi tausun, there is one more condition col1=col5 and col1!= col4 may also be valid in such a case col1 needs to be updated with col4